# Linking two subprocess output to another subprocesses input

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

so I have a problem here. I have a subprocess that reads one file and redirects the output to a subprocess pipe. I have another subprocess that does the exact same thing. What I want to do is run a diff command on each of these outputs. Possibly using another subprocess, but somehow reading in both stdouts from the other two. Heres an example.

```
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['samtools', 'view', 'file1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['samtools', 'view', 'file2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And theoretically this is what I want to do...

```
proc3 = subprocess.Popen(['diff', proc1.communicate()[0], proc2.communicate()[0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If anyone doesn't understand what I mean, I can explain better but hopefully if you know anything about subprocesses then you will get this.

Comment: I don't think it can be done like this, because a process only has one stdin. You'll probably need to write the output to some temporary files and then run the third process on those.

Comment: `diff` works on files, so you will have to give it something that quacks like file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

outside, inside = os.pipe()

one = Popen(['/path/to/one'], stdout = inside)
two = Popen(['/path/to/two'], stdout = inside)

merge = Popen(['/path/to/merge'], stdin = outside)
```

This runs no diff function on the outputs. It just channels both programs to the input of the 'merge' process.

Reading differences between 2 inputs channeled into a single pipe, will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that a good way to achieve that would be to redirect the output of the two initial processes to two different [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) and use them as files in the third process to get the input.